# How do you use completely free software to create ovf files for VMware ESXi?

Tags: vmware, virtualization

Ok, so let's say that I want to try virtualization in my environment. I want to use ESXi to do that because it is free. I can use the install disk and setup a box to run the ESXi Host.

I'm not sure if the VMware Infrastructure Client is free for one thing. You can use it to attach an ovf file (a packaged VM). The problem I had is creating an ovf file that worked. The free converter didn't do the trick.

Does anyone have any tips or guidelines?

Comment: So why was my question downvoted? I thought it usually gave a reason for downvotes but I don't see one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no, the VMware client is not free:

*"Further, managing a VMware ESXi host with VMware vCenter Server requires a VMware vCenter Server Agent for each host, only available with the purchase of a VMware Infrastructure license (Foundation, Standard, or Enterprise)."*

From this VMware page:

http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/uses.html

Comment: So is the Free ESXi Server free download useless? How do I get this box working with a virtual machine?

Comment: Nah, it's still useful, but it's much more difficult.  You have to do everything via command lines, SSH, FTP, that kind of thing.  If you're just getting started, I'd use VMware Server, which is free and much easier to manage.

Comment: agreed. It is much easier and I've used it. I just thought that it was supposed to be better to use the ESXi because it wasn't dependent on an OS.

Comment: The answer is out-dated and the link that documented a non-free restriction is broken.  If it was non-free at one time, the client is in the vSphere Hypervisor (Free Product) download area and is useable without a paid-for license.  Recent use of download and free use of the client did not require a temporary evaluation license.  saschabeaumont's answer is the more accurate one.  The client and hypervisor were not overly useful until a free vSphere Hypervisor license was applied to the ESXi server.

Answer (score 3):

The **VMware Infrastructure Client** is free with certain restrictions. You just download it over the web from an installed ESXi host.

You need licenses to enable vMotion, but for a single host there's no problem.

We're using ESXi (free) with the VI Client (free) and getting *tons* better performance than VMware Server (also free). I wasn't so sure about the VI Client thing until I talked to someone else that had a working setup, it's a bit confusing and definitely not "obvious" if you're new to the various enterprise level VMware solutions.

Edit: This was true for ESX3, things change and it is no longer true. See comments for ESX4/5 solutions.

Comment: how do you create the ovf file then?

Comment: I've never used OVF files, just installed the VMs directly via the VI Client

Comment: In the infrastructure client: File -> Export -> To OVF (or similar).

Comment: The download of the client can be done from any workstation from the vSphere Hypervisor download area on vmware.com.  It is not required to download the client from an installed ESXi host.  In fact, though the server screen offers a URL pointing to the installed server and mentions it may be used to obtain software, on a clean install of VMware-VMvisor-Installer-5.1.0-799733.x86_64.iso, it does not appear that a webserver is running on the ESXi host, and is seems that for the download to be available from the host, some additional configuration is required that is not disclosed in this answer.

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1029925 appears to imply that the client is not available from the ESXi host since 4.1.  The ESXi host now redirects the user to a vmware.com download site, but this redirect fails without indicating problem cause when the client does not have internet access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VI Client is free with ESXi, you just don't get advanced features.

For creating an OVF you should have a look at VMware Studio, a new Beta was released recently.